# Shortcut for changing tabs->spaces->tabs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, indentation, shortcut

I know I can change indentation by:

```
File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > ANY_LANGUAGE > Tabs and Indents > Use tab character
```

but in my legacy project there is a mix of indents in different files. Is there any keyboard shortcut in IDE for changing spaces to tabs and vice versa? Or how can I set up one for all or specified language files?

Comment: You can navigate to any action as shown here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/navigating-to-action.html. That page also provides a link to configuring a key binding if needed.

Answer (score 67):

To toggle between tabs and spaces:

On the main menu, choose **Edit → Convert Indents**, and then choose **To Spaces** or **To Tabs** respectively. Read more about [Changing Indentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/changing-indentation.html).

You can quickly do the same with **Navigating to Action** menu by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and type `convert indents` in the field:

[image]

If you want to set spaces indents by default, go to **Settings → Editor → Code Style → Java**, make sure the **Use tab character** checkbox is unchecked and set the **Indent** value:

[image]

Comment: ok, it's a shortcut for **converting** all current indents in open document but when I create a new line it's still in the old convention. what's the shortcut for **changing convention** of each new line, each new indent?

Comment: I'm aware how to change it. I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for this action (or if there isn't default shortcut, I'm looking for the way how to set up custom shortcut for it).

Comment: are you looking for the shortcut to change this global IDEA setting?

Comment: I'm not sure what to mean by *global setting*. I'm looking for a shortcut which will change my indenting politics in current, for example groovy, file from space to tabs and conversly whenever I use it.

Comment: I see, not sure it's possible, but the question is interesting and finding the solution will be useful.

Answer (score 11):

In IntelliJ IDEA, to convert existing tabs to spaces or vice versa, use **File** → **Edit** → **Convert Indents** → **To Spaces** (or **To Tabs**). The *Reformat code* shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> will also do this, while applying other changes.

To tell the IDE to insert spaces for tabs *going forward*, go to **File** → **Settings** → **Editor** → **Code Style** → **(whatever language)** → **Tabs and Indents** → then *uncheck* **Use tab character**.

There's another setting that you may also want to pay attention to that controls file indents: **File** → **Settings** → **Detect and use existing file indents for editing**. This setting is not always consistent for some reason. If you *uncheck* it, then IntelliJ may or may not auto-indent new lines in your file with tab characters.

For example, let's say each line in one of your java file already begins with a tab character. You want to leave those, say for source control reasons, but you want all new code to substitute spaces for tabs, including indents. So you have **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** *unchecked* and you have **Use tab character** *unchecked* for Java. You're clearly telling IntelliJ not to insert a tab, even for indents.

Well, nonetheless, when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of a new line that begins with a tab, IntelliJ goes ahead and adds a tab character at the beginning of the next line you just created. Hit tab again and it adds spaces (as expected based on your settings).

If someone knows how to resolve this somewhat irritating unexpected behavior, please comment. Granted, it's pretty easily resolved by first doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> to change all tabs in the file to spaces and then going forward you won't see this strangeness. But of course that modifies source history for any changed lines.

Comment: Reformat code does not successfully do this on latest Pycharm on Mac OS. This is with detect style turned off, and the proper tab length set to spaces.

Comment: The above question pertains specifically to IntelliJ IDEA. But perhaps this may help regarding PyCharm?: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformat-file-dialog.html

Comment: This is a complete answer - thanks

Comment: there's also the option of inheriting style config from somewhere else, disable that.

Answer (score 10):

Select a folder, do :

- *search & replace* inside it by `Cmd+Shift+R` in MacOs for eg.
- check regex option
- provide `[\t]` as text to be replaced
- provide spaces as
  text for replacement

as the **Convert Indents** action does it file per file, which is not very convenient with big project.

[image]

Note: After you still need to change default preference to use spaces as indentation like explained by @DimaSan

Comment: Ridiculous that you can run "Reformat Code" on all files, but not "Replace Tabs".

Answer (score 1):

*Editor* > *Code Style* > *Detect and use existing file indents for editing*

This will make "tab" into four spaces, if the file is indented with spaces and
also lets you show a notification when a file is indented with tabs, and offer to change it to spaces for you.

Note: I am on the pro version on Intellij, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have checked them but as I said `in my legacy project there is a mix of indents in different files`, so I'm still using for a faster way then @DimaSan proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat each file to apply your styling in Code > Reformat code menu.
On Windows, the related shortcut is Ctrl-Alt-L.

Selecting a package will give you an option to reformat all source files including sub-directories, optionally filtered by file extension.

This is as of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3 for Java files.

Comment: What I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as well.  Thank you very much. This was annoying me

Comment: That command (Ctrl+Alt+L) reformats everything. What the OP asked for, and what I'd like, is something to CONVERT TABS TO SPACES. That's it. Nothing else. The rest of the formatting may still be wonky, but at least it'll be wonky the same way on all displays.

Comment: @BillEvans As commented by jonrshape in the OP question, keyboard shortcuts can be assigned to any action, see [IdeaJ help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)

Comment: Yes, but *what is the action* for converting all tabs to spaces — not only leading tabs, but also embedded tabs? And not just 1 tab -> 4 spaces or whatever, but 1 tab -> 1, 2, 3, or 4 spaces, as contextually appropriate.

That’s what we’re trying to determine. Once I know how to do that, I can make accessing it more or less convenient, depending on how often (rarely) I need to perform it.